# Why to register HandleError in global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

When a new MVC3 project is created, [HandleError] attribute is by default registered as GlobalFilter in GLobal.asax. However, if I comment it and execute following (with custom error mode on), it still works. I do see ErrorView with ErrorInfo model populated. Then what is the need for registering HandleError in Global.asax?

```
  [HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(NullReferenceException),View = "ErrorView")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException();
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is setting the default MVC exception handling policy. It will render the `/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml` view when an unhandled exception arises, without you having to explicitly add the HandleError attribute on every controller or action.

You can then add more specific `HandleError` attributes  to your controller and\or actions, so you could display another error view than the default view or handle a more expecific exception type.

For the HandleError filters to work (global or not), you just need to make sure the custom errors are enabled in the web.config, as in `<customErrors mode="On" />` (The default is RemoteOnly, so during development they won´t be executed)

This is nicely explained (following an example) [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gduthie/archive/2011/03/17/get-to-know-action-filters-in-asp-net-mvc-3-using-handleerror.aspx)